# Forward button using Post/Get method in PHP

Tags: php, forms, redirect, forwarding

Firstly i should probably let you know what i'm doing.
I have a website that lists all of the text messages sent out by my company (lets call this list.php).
There is also a page that allows us to send messages using forms. This has two textareas for Phone Number and message, and a submit button (lets call this send.php).
Next to the message, on the far right, there is a forward icon.
What i'd like to do is:

-When the forward icon is clicked, it grabs that text message, redirects the list.php page to send.php with the corresponding message already pasted into the Message textarea of send.php.

Any sort of idea on how to do this?
Any and all help will be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Here's a code of my send page:

```
include 'lib/jqmPhp.php';
$j = new jqmPhp();
$j->head()->title('Imezio SMS Control Panel');
$j->head()->add(new jqmLink('jquery-fix.css'));
$j->head()->add(new jqmScript('index.js'));

$p = new jqmPage('Imezio SMS Control Panel');
$p->title('Imezio SMS Control Panel');
$bt = $p->header()->addButton('SMS History', 'list3.php', 'a', 'home', false, false, true);
$bt->rel('external');

$form = new jqmForm('sendForm');
$form->method('post');
$form->add(new jqmInput('to', 'to', 'text', '', 'Phone Number', '', true));
$char = $form->add(new jqmInput('msg', 'msg', 'text', '', 'Message', '', true));
$char->attribute('span id','charcount');
$form->add(new jqmInput('submit', 'submit', 'submit', 'submit', '', 'b', true));

$p->addContent($form);
$j->addPage($p);
echo $j;
```

This is using JQMPHP

Comment: Do you have code for what you have tried?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't tried anything. As i have no idea how to even start. I've been told you can get it done via get/post methods, however i've never worked with these methods.

Comment: If you look at other posts, they typically post code and have more specific questions.  This question is too broad.  Try something and if you get stuck and can't find a solution, then ask.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a tad unfortunate, i've been looking on here for a while. Can't find anything that would specifically help me with this situation.

Comment: No i don't have a MySQL database